# Navigation changes from transparent to colored background

Tags: html, css

I have been at this for 10 hours straight, I have tried different types of positiong, but it's just not working. I can't replicate this interesting effect where you scroll down the page and the navigation changes from a transparent background, to a white background. The example can be found at http://www.bakkenbaeck.no/ Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hi, can you post the code you have please. Did you use something like firebug to inspect the source? Defenately see some jQuery being used in that transition

Comment: I used firebug and it seems he has two headers at the top of the page. You can see this effect if you disable the position:fixed on the header element

Comment: Use crome and then inspect the element click on the resources tab and locate the folder scripts then have a look at the script jquery.pagescroller.js it is neatly commented out

Comment: *facepalm* I know html and css. I don't know jQuery, but I suspected it after looking at the source code. Thanks at least I am not spending another 10h on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR This effect is accomplished with not only HTML and CSS but also needs some JS to pull this one off.

I am guessing a little bit as to what you are referring to specifically on that example you gave but I will assume for this post that you are referring to the change that happens once the user scrolls down past the initial full height image where you see the logo change from white to gray and the background of this nav area turns white.

Not knowing your skill level/knowledge its a bit tough to make assumptions about what is going to give you direction, but I'll try my best. What is happening here is the creative use of CSS z-index, some javascript, and duplicate menus. If you think of a web page as a stack of paper, then the first piece of paper is the menu which is on top of the second page, the opening image, then the third page, the the next (duplicate) menu. The duplicate menu is positioned exactly under the first menu. As you scroll down you remove that middle image layer and the new navigation is exposed via some JS. There is a page scroll event listener (javascript) that is checking where the page is currently scrolled to. Once the user reaches the point where the logo and navigation need to start changing, the javascript kicks in and starts to set the height of the first navigation to 1px smaller for every 1px past the scroll point you've gone all the way until it gets a height of 0px effectively hiding it. If you take a look inside of chrome web tools by inspecting both navigations, you can see this happening (the height of the navigation shrinks) as you scroll.

I can see that the site is using http://pagescroller.com/ which is probably the plugin they are using to trigger the height adjustments I was describing.

Hope that gives you some direction!

Answer (score 0):

Reaserch Paralax scrolling if you not familiar with js there are numerous tutorials online and you will find it very easy if you follow them step by step here are some that I have used:

http://www.impressivewebs.com/parallax-scrolling-scripts-plugins/

It's really easy don't let jQuery intimidate you there is plenty examples on google!